# Find the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{13Z }\times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{13Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I was finding the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{13Z }\times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{13Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ has no nontrivial subgroup, I thought (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) are the only four subgroup. But I think I am making some mistake. Please help. Also, is there any general formula for it?

Comment: Those are elements, not subgroups.

Comment: Actually I mean to say <(0,1)>, subgroup generated by (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $U$ is a subgroup which contains an element $(0,a)$ with $a\ne 0$, then $\{0\}\times \Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z$ must be a subgroup of $U$. This provides all subgroups.

Comment: What about $\langle (a,0)\rangle$?

Comment: This works similarly.

Comment: What about the diagonal subgroup?

Comment: Good question: its in there generated by (1,1). My hint is answering the question what subgroups could be there when you already have constructed a collection of subgroups.